# Significado de ditados populares em "O Cortiço"

Tags: significado, ditados, proverbios, literatura

**O Cortiço: Capítulo IX**

"Quem não pode com o tempo, não inventa modas"

"Quem não quer ser lobo não lhe vista a pele"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os dois ditados têm mesmo significado: quem não quer arcar com as consequências de uma ação, não a pratique; quem não quer enfrentar as dificuldades de uma situação, não se meta nela.

No caso d'[*O Cortiço* de Aluísio de Azevedo](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv000015.pdf) (originalmente publicado em 1890), um homem enrolou-se com uma moça menor. A mãe da moça exige que ele case com ela, mas ele parece não o querer fazer. E então estes ditados são proferidos por umas mulheres, que querem dizer que se ele não queria casar com a moça, então que não se tivesse enrolado com ela (ênfase minha):

> — Como, não casa?!...
>   — Era só o que faltava!
>   — Tinha graça!
>   — Então mais ninguém pode contar com a honra de sua filha?
>   — Se não queria casar pra que fez mal?
>   — **Quem não pode com o tempo não inventa modas!**
>   — Ou ele casa ou sai daqui com os ossos em sopa!
>   — **Quem não quer ser lobo não lhe vista a pele!**

O primeiro ditado—*quem não quer ser lobo não lhe vista a pele*—é muito comum. Eu sempre o associei a uma história de um cordeiro que se vestiu de lobo e foi morto por aldeões que o tomaram mesmo por lobo.

O segundo—*quem não pode com o tempo não inventa modas*—eu nunca tinha ouvido. O ditado poderia talvez basear-se na efemeridade da moda—modo de vestir e agir dum momento—que não sobrevive à passagem do tempo. Mas parece-me mais plausível que a base do ditado esteja em  duas aceções menos óbvias de *moda* e *tempo*: [*moda* (Michaelis 8)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=moda) ou [*modinha* (Michaelis 2 & 3)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?palavra=modinha&r=0&f=0&t=0) também significa ‘canção, cantiga’; e [*tempo* (Michaelis 12)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=tempo) também significa o [*andamento* (Michaelis 4)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?palavra=andamento&r=0&f=0&t=0) de uma música, ou seja o “modo ou rapidez com que é executado um trecho de música”. Portanto, não invente cantigas quem não aguenta o andamento delas.

Comment: Nunca ouvi nenhum dos dois mas o ditado lupino é auto-explicativo. Eu entenderia facilmente.  Quanto ao "... não inventa modas", acho a tua primeira explicação mais plausível.  A segunda me parece muito erudita para ser um provérbio ou ditado.  Ditados costumam referir-se a coisas muito simples

Comment: A segunda frase do lobo quer dizer que se a pessoa não quer ser confundida com alguém de caráter duvidoso, não deve se portar como tal. As frases não significam a mesma coisa.

Comment: @Centaurus O problema da minha primeira explicação é que não chega a ser bem uma explicação: aquilo não me sugere uma imagem concreta; que significaria não poder com o tempo ou inventar uma moda no sXIX? A segunda interpretação oferece uma imagem contreta. É verdade que *tempo* no sentido de andamento seria provavelmente um termo técnico; *moda* para 'cantiga' é até termo popular. Mas também não sei quão popular é o ditado; é muito raro no Google Books. Sugere-me cantigas ao desafio, em que duas ou mais pessoas vão cantando de improviso em despique umas com as outras.

Comment: @AndréLyra Parece-me que estás a fazer um interpretação muito literal e muito colada à minha história do cordeiro e do lobo. Eu tenho visto o ditado usado com significado mais geral.

Comment: @Bruno O contexto é que o texto que eu citei. Se seguires o link, tens lá *O Cortiço* todo. Ali os dois ditados ali resumem-se à outra frase que uma mulher diz, "se não queria casar pra que fez mal?" [por que desflorou a moça].

Comment: Mesmo no contexto, a primeira frase é sobre ele pagar por ter se metido a fazer alguma coisa da cabeça dele (inventou moda); a segunda frase também tem de pagar pelo que fez, mas por ter agido como o lobo que fez mal pra donzela. São motivos diferentes que levam ele a pagar pelo que fez. Mesmo assim, a segunda frase ainda julga o caráter dele o comparando ao lobo, enquanto a primeira apenas revela que ele não mede as consequências de seus atos.

Answer (score 0):

Expressões comuns usadas no Brasil. Apesar de que "não lhe vista a pele" é usada individualmente para aquele contexto, ironizando a situação com o contexto do lobo.

*Quem não pode com o tempo, 'não inventa moda'* - não inventa moda significa não inventar possibilidades, não criar caso, não criar idéias malucas.

> Hoje está fazendo 50 graus, garoto. Onde você pensa que vai com esse casaco? Não invente moda!
>
> Nossos salários acabaram de ser reduzidos, como você acha que vamos bancar mais dois filhos? Não invente moda!
>
> Seu cabelo está ótimo com essa cor, nem pense em pintar, não invente moda.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma expressão do inglês que é muito popular: "If you can't do the time, don't do the crime". Significa "se tu não podes aguentar/suportar o tempo (no sentido de tempo de prisão), não cometa o crime". O sentido é mais parecido com "quem inventa, aguenta".

"Inventar moda" geralmente é usada para caracterizar alguém que quer fazer coisas desnecessárias em uma situação, ou modificar a maneira como as coisas usualmente são feitas, adicionar mais trabalho do que o combinado, ou introduzir novas ideias, mudar algum costume.

Talvez a expressão do livro queira dizer algo tipo "você não conseguirá se safar com desculpas inéditas, pois você vai sofrer as consequências de qualquer jeito".

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que você só respondeu sobre um dos dois ditados, e que sua explicação levanta a pergunta: será que "inventar moda" já existia com essa acepção na época da escrita do livro?